# In Hive, how to get the values from within tag definitions in an XML?

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, hive, hiveql

How could the tag definitions be considered while parsing XMLs in Hive query? Below is my XML to be parsed:

```
<Parents>
    <Parent>
      <emp id="A12345">
        <acc name="perm_ID">44444</acc>
        <acc name="temp_ID">55555</acc>
      </emp>
    </Parent>
</Parents>
```

There are 3 fields EmpID, PermID and TempID. Expected output is:

```
EmpID   PermID  TempID
A12345  44444   55555
```

Comment: How did you try? Do you want one generic XPath for all 3 values or 3 separate expressions?

Comment: Any approach is fine. I'm curious to know how the EmpID value could be extracted and how other 2 ID's could be separated as per name condition. Thanks in advance! @JaSON

Comment: Not sure how to make queries in Hive, but you can get values with XPaths: `//emp/@id`, `//acc[@name="perm_ID"]/text()`, `//acc[@name="temp_ID"]/text()`

Comment: XPaths provided by @JaSON are also valid ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XPATH()` returns list of nodes, `XPATH_STRING()` returns scalar string. If you have many emp in XML array, use `XPATH()` to get a list of Id attributes + `lateral view explode` to explode rows, then use `Id` to parametrize XPATH_STRING to get elements from corresponding emp.

See this demo(Hive):

```
with mytable as (
select '<Parents>
    <Parent>
      <emp id="A12345">
        <acc name="perm_ID">44444</acc>
        <acc name="temp_ID">55555</acc>
      </emp>
    </Parent>
</Parents>' as xml
)

select e.Id as EmpId, 
      XPATH_STRING(t.xml,concat('/Parents/Parent/emp[@id="',e.Id,'"]/acc[@name="perm_ID"]/text()')) permID,
      XPATH_STRING(t.xml,concat('/Parents/Parent/emp[@id="',e.Id,'"]/acc[@name="temp_ID"]/text()')) tempID
  from mytable t
       lateral view outer explode(XPATH(t.xml, '/Parents/Parent/emp/@id')) e as  Id
```

Result:

```
empid   permid    tempid    
A12345  44444     55555
```

In this demo you can see how to deal with arrays and scalar elements and attributes, how to parametrize your xpath using values extracted by other xpath.

See also other Hive XPATH functions: [XPathUDF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+XPathUDF)